# Google Tag Manager - variables undefined during custom HTML execution

Tags: google-tag-manager

## Situation

I want to implement conversion tracking for an affiliate marketer on our page. But when I send the call, the otherwise perfectly defined variables cease to be defined ... I am at a loss.

[image: Debug Mode Tag Manager]

All these tags work nicely and have access to the relevant variables.
E.g. Order Id or Order Revenue:
[image]

## Problem

However, the AWIN - Conversion HTML does not. Please find the tag below (custom HTML).

```html
<script>
var test = {{Debug Mode}} ? 1 : 0
  
if (typeof AWIN != "undefined" && typeof AWIN.Tracking != "undefined") {
    AWIN.Tracking.Sale = {};
    AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = parseFloat({{dlv - Thank You Page - Order Revenue}}).toFixed(2);
    AWIN.Tracking.Sale.channel = {{js - Last UTM Source}};
    AWIN.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = {{dlv - Thank You Page - Order ID}};
    AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = "{{js - AWIN - Commission Group}}:" + parseFloat({{dlv - Thank You Page - Order Revenue}}).toFixed(2);
    AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = {{dlv - Currency}};
    AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = {{dlv - Thank You Page - Coupon Code Name}};
    AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = test;

    AWIN.Tracking.run();
}
</script>
```

The tag fires and executes the code, but all relevant variables are undefined now.
The `dataLayer` variables seem to have moved on (because new elements have been pushed onto the `dataLayer`. I verified that by adding a `console.log(dataLayer[dataLayer.length -1])` which did not print the purchase event but cookie_consent_marketing.

Comment: Wild guess, but check your custom tags and custom variables if you are doing a pop() anywhere on the datalayer variable. While this will retrieve the last element, it will also remove it from the array.

Comment: @eike Pierstorff pretty good guess, but I don’t think so. Weirdly enough when removing the enforcement of firing the base tag before the variables are defined

Comment: Ah, I completely misunderstood your last sentence, so it wasn't even a good guess :-) I get a sense of deja vu from looking at your setup, since we have almost exactly the same complement of tags. Btw Awin can supply you with a custom template (at least they did for us), although there is no guarantee that this will solve your problem.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff interesting with the custom template. For some reason there are two community gallery tags related to AWIN. Journey and Conversion. Unfortunately, it’s pretty hard to verify what those are doing. I still tried them, but without much success (couldn’t find the needed calls in network tab). How are they supplying you with a custom template tag? Do they send files over? Or do they unlock it somehow? I tried to build a custom template tag myself, but not much success so far.

Comment: Our account manager asked their account manager. However those might be the same as in the template gallery (at least they go by the same name, journey tag being the pageview tracker and conversion for purchases).